# Some Android clients disconnect and then retry HTTP request after 15 seconds, even though timeout is larger

Tags: android, http

I have an Android app that makes HTTP requests to a server, which I control. This server relays the requests to another server, which I don't control and is currently severely overloaded. In order to cope with the delays in the remote server, I have increased all timeouts I am aware of.

In my own server, I am seeing some clients (the Android app) abort the HTTP request after 15 seconds and then retry the same request, even though I have set the connection and read timeouts to be be much larger than that.

nginx in my server reports that as a 499 error in the logs, and it always happens around 15 seconds after the request arrived.

Using wireshark on my server, I have positively verified that it is the client disconnecting (in sends a FIN packet) and then immediately retrying the same request.

I haven't been able to reproduce the problem using my own phone. Even if I make the server introduce an artificial delay, my phone respects the timeout I have set. On a recent update I started sending some basic information about the user (phone model, android version, current connection type) to see if I can detect a pattern for the problematic phones, but haven't noticed any pattern so far.

I was previously using `HttpClient` on the app, and tried several approaches to correct this problem, but the timeouts and retries kept happening. Then I switched to `HttpURLConnection`, and I'm seeing the same behavior. The `HttpURLConnection` version of the code is really simple, almost verbatim from the examples, save for different timeout values:

```
InputStream is = null;
try
{
  URL url = new URL("my.server.com" + paramString);
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  conn.setReadTimeout(180 * 1000);
  conn.setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000);
  conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
  conn.setDoInput(true);
  conn.connect();

  int response = conn.getResponseCode();
  is = conn.getInputStream();
}
```

I have found no mention of this behavior anywhere on the documentation. Any ideas on where this 15 seconds timeout is being set and why my own timeout aren't respected?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue myself, after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172752/httpsurlconnection-and-intermittent-connections) issue I was able to solve it with the top answer. your request would look like the following after the change:

```
...
URL url = new URL("my.server.com" + paramString);
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
...
```

Comment: Sorry I missed your reply, as several months had passed. I believe I did try what you mention, but only at app start and not on every connection as I assumed the setting was "app wide". I will try again and will update here if it works. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is app wide I don't remember how we implemented it but there's no context in the question to show an app wide implementation.